# filter variables in r studio

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to filter values within a variable in a dataset called `brazilcorona`.

This dataset contains a variable called `data`, which contains the date (year/month/day) that the covid infection ocurred, for example `2020-03-14` (14th march of 2020).

Specifically, I am trying to create a new vector and **eliminate all the dates that are previous to 2020-05-15 (15th may of 2020).**

In order to to so, I tried the following code 
`newdata <- filter (Brazilcorona, data > 2020-05-15)`

When I try to run the code above, R shows the error `not meaningful for factors`

In other words, I would like to create a new vector that has only dates after may 15th, that is, occurs **after** `2020-05-15`.

Could someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the date to `date` class and compare the dates

```
library(dplyr)

new_data <- brazilcorona %>% 
              mutate(data = as.Date(data)) %>% 
              filter(data > as.Date('2020-05-15'))
```

In base R :

```
new_data <- subset(transform(brazilcorona, data = as.Date(data)), 
                   data > as.Date('2020-05-15'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, Ronak. When I run those codes, I am able to create a new vector. However, R shows me "No data available in table", that is, ```0 obs```. Do you know what i am doing wrong? I simply copied and pasted the code above... Tks

Comment: What does `dim(new_data)` return?

Comment: It rerturns the following : ```[1]  0 14```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the output of `dput(head(Brazilcorona, 2))` in your post?

Comment: alright, done :)

Comment: Your `dput` gives me an error but I think you are not using correct dataframe name and column name. It looks like your dataframe name is `brazilcorona` and date column is called `data`. Please make these adjustments in the above code, don't directly copy-paste. .

Comment: i edited it. The variable is called ```data``` and the dataset is ```brazilcorona```. Even tough I made those adjustments, the code you passed persists with the ```0 obs error```. If it may help, the csv data I am using is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/brazilcorona.csv

Comment: @Andre well, the data has no observation after 15th May. The last observation is of 15th May hence you get 0 rows. If you change the last line to `filter(data >= as.Date('2020-05-15'))` you'll get data for 15th May.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Ronak. It is running fine now. Thank you, really.

Comment: Hi Ronak. I just sent you an inbox message in twitter. When you are free, could you please check it ? Tks!